# Skip first index of array validation rule?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

Good Evening Devs,
I'm trying to skip the first index of the array while applying validation rule and this is what I tried so far

```
$validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(),([
            'inventories.0'      => 'bail',
            'inventories'        => 'required|array|filled',
            'quantities.0'       => 'bail',
            'quantities.*'       => 'required|array|filled',
            'required.0'         => 'bail',
            'required.*'         => 'required|array|filled',
        ]));
```

But it's not working, any ideas? 
I'm trying to add multiple dynamic fields, but want to skip the first index of it.
Please review the picture given below to get the clear picture of the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$validatedData = Validator::make($request->except(['inventories[0],quantities[0],required[0]']),([
    'inventories.*'        => 'required|array|filled',
    'quantities.*'       => 'required|array|filled',
    'required.*'         => 'required|array|filled',
]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Bail is not used for skipping an entry. But it may be used for skipping validation logic. 
for example,

```
'phone' => 'bail|numeric|unique:users'
```

In this case, if somehow the entered phone number is not numeric, it will not check the third validation (i.e. whether the phone number is unique in 'users' table or not).

For your case, you should not use "$request->all()". You should use "request()->except(['inventories[0], quantities[0], required[0]'])" instead

Answer (score 1):

This is perhaps, not the best practice.  You're trying to allow the presentation layer to have a direct influence over the data / logic layer of your application.  It would probably be better to only send over the data you want to validate rather than sending over everything and they tying to get your validation (and other logic) to ignore the first array element.

Is it an api call or a standard web form you are submitting?  If it is an api call, can you not build up your data of only the rows you want to send over, before you make the call?

This will keep your logic layer much cleaner, and allow you to change the ui much easier without affecting the logic, and it being tightly coupled.

Just a suggestion.